# How to restart Teamviewer daemon programmatically?

Tags: teamviewer

I've installed TV as a server on a Ubuntu 12.04 box running 24/7. Unfortunately, the daemon service sometimes bugs and disconnects. I can fix this at the terminal with :

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon <stop/start>
```

But this requires local access to the server, which is not always possible. I could make a script to periodically check (start and stop) the service,

But I do not know how to issue a `sudo` command within the script.
Can anyone help? Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Probably you don't need a script but a cron job that runs the command. Type `sudo crontab -e`, then append the following:

```
0 * * * * service teamviewerd restart
```

**This will run the command each hour sharp**, so you may want to modify it or be pending because you will be disconnected. You may also want to know why teamviewer disconnects, so a peek to the logfiles and a bug report may be necessary.

Answer (score 8):

Trying “sudo teamviewer –daemon start” doesn’t actually do anything for me(Linux Mint) – so the solution is to:

```
sudo teamviewer --daemon enable
```

If the daemon service certainly stop working then this resolution start daemon again, TV is ready to use.

[Found Solution over this page](http://www.randomhacks.co.uk/the-teamviewer-daemon-is-not-running-please-start-the-daemon-ubuntu/)

[Link to Another Solution](https://gist.github.com/Lh4cKg/bd425b55c49c8687d36a2391e4311a38)

Comment: @Zanna: In this case it really is the same since the Teamviewer packages are the same.

Comment: Work for me. If daemon was disabled before `sudo teamviewer --daemon start` don't work.  `sudo teamviewer --daemon enable` solution work. Ubuntu 12.04. Thanks.

Comment: Worked for me to start team viewer again. (It was previously showing connection not ready).